# How to implement polymorphic list deserialization with GSON in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2, moshi

I have a data feed that is returning a list that could be either of three types ( Say type A, B and C ). All of the types above share 2 properties, the rest of the properties is specific to the type. I tried using the pattern.

```
abstract class Parent (val type: String, val id: String)
```

And

```
data class TypeA(override val type: String ... )
data class TypeB(override val type: String ... )
```

I am using Retrofit and trying to deserialize the list to

```
List<? extends Parent>
```

which in Kotlin should be

```
List<out Parent>
```

However GSON is throwing a deserializing error on instantiating the parent class which is abstract.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public com.XX.Parent() with no args
```

Any ideas how I can implement this in Kotlin?

Comment: I think you're missing more of the exception message?

Comment: For now I wrote an explicit Adapter for my abstract class, not sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you have Moshi tagged in your question, I'll give you a way of doing it using MOshi's `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory`. You can basically parse something into different types, depending on the value of the object's property.

First thing you'll do is declared your parent type as a sealed class and have the other types extend from it:

```
sealed class Parent(val type: String){
    data class TypeA(override val type: String, ... ): Parent(type) 
    data class TypeB(override val type: String, ... ): Parent(type) 
}
```

now you're gonna tell Moshi how to parse `Parent` objects. You do that registering a `PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory`:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
      .add(PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(Parent::class.java, "type")
          .withSubtype(TypeA::class.java, "typeA")
          .withSubtype(TypeB::class.java, "typeB")
      .build()
```

with that, if the value of the property "type" is "typeA", it will deserialize into a `TypeA` instance. like wise to `TypeB`, if property "type" is "typeB"

You can look another example here:
https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.java